# Firebase Database No such instance field error

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two activities. I am trying to retrieve data from the firebase database, but there is nothing. The debugger tells me that there is "No such instance field" in the databaseRefer and mFirebaseInstance variables. I used the database in the same manner for another activity and I was able to retrieve the data. When I changes activities, it just gave me the "no such instance field" error. I don't understand why it works in one activity but not in another. Can someone help me with this please?

```
    DatabaseReference databaseRefer;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    databaseRefer = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Physical Stats").child(userID);

    databaseRefer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            physicalStats[0]=Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("Str").getValue().toString());
            physicalStats[1]=Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("StrE").getValue().toString());
            physicalStats[2]=Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("Stm").getValue().toString());
            physicalStats[3]=Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("Spd").getValue().toString());
            physicalStats[4]=Float.parseFloat(dataSnapshot.child("Flx").getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so the problem is in getReference() method. dont put string "Physical Stats" inside that let it be empty. make a child method for "Physical Stats" like you did with userId.
`getReference().child("Physical Stats").child(userId);`